# How to add badge to UINavigationItem (UIBarButtonItem) - Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

Dose ios providing badge on UIBarButtonItem? 
if not then how to do it programmatically or use any library(what are the best library)
[image: Screen]

In image i want to show badge on UIBarButtonItem (Refresh button icon) like red color round or numbers any thing.

Comment: @rkkanojai I don't think ios provides badge number on UIBarButtonItem. You need to add a label to display badge count.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [MIBadgeButton](https://github.com/mustafaibrahim989/MIBadgeButton-Swift) its working like a charm.

```
var appNotificationBarButton: MIBadgeButton!      // Make it global
self.appNotificationBarButton = MIBadgeButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 40))
self.appNotificationBarButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "bell"), for: .normal)
self.appNotificationBarButton.badgeEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 10)
self.appNotificationBarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.appNotificationClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
let App_NotificationBarButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.appNotificationBarButton)
self.navigationItems.rightBarButtonItem = App_NotificationBarButton
```